# Правильное создание ссылок на структуры и хранение этих ссылок в самих структурах

Tags: rust

**Вопрос:** Как правильно создавать ссылки на структуру и хранить эту ссылку внутри этойже структуры? Ссылки будут использоваться в потоках которые будет создавать эта структура.

**Код:**

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::RwLock;

pub struct Nanite {
    self_arc:RwLock<Option<Arc<Nanite>>>,

    i_num:RwLock<usize>,
}

impl Nanite {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Nanite> {
        let arc_new = Arc::new(
            Nanite {
                self_arc:RwLock::new(None),
                i_num:RwLock::new(0usize),
            }
        );
        {
            let mut write_self = arc_new.self_arc.write().unwrap();
            *write_self = Some(arc_new.clone());
        }
        arc_new
    }

    pub fn plus(&self) {
        if let Ok(mut write) = self.i_num.write() {
            *write += 1000;
        }
    }

    pub fn clone_self(&self) -> Arc<Nanite> {
        if let Ok(read) = self.self_arc.read() {
            match *read {
                Some(ref v) => {
                    return v.clone();
                },
                None => {
                    panic!("Please normal self for Nanite");
                }
            }
        }
        panic!("Please normal self for Nanite");
    }
    pub fn start(&self) {
        for _i in 0..5 {
            let this_self = self.clone_self();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let this_self = this_self;
                this_self.plus();
            });
        }
    }
    pub fn get_i_num(&self) -> Option<usize>{
        if let Ok(get) = self.i_num.read() {
            return Some(*get);
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let nan = Nanite::new();
    nan.start();
    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(2_000));
    println!("I_NUM:{}", nan.get_i_num().unwrap());
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5538a088480521c526c38a2527d57ba1&version=stable

**Проблема 1:** А правильно ли это  `self_arc:RwLock<Option<Arc<Nanite>>>`

**Проблема 2:** Может существует более эффективный способ?

Comment: По-моему, более продуктивный вопрос — зачем вам структуры со встроенным многопоточным доступом к себе и повсеместные `Arc`? `RwLock` это синхронизационный примитив с ненулевой стоимостью использования, `Arc` тоже использует атомарные операции при любом клонировании. Вообще-то дизайн Rust должен подталкивать людей к хорошему: минимизировать параллельное использование изменяемых данных и вместо этого передавать между потоками данные, удовлетворяющие `Send`.

Comment: Хорошо, предложите другой примитив синхронизации уж точно с нулевой стоимостью. а так вопрос решен.

Comment: Чтобы предложить, нужно понять, что на самом деле хотелось сделать. Значит, нужен один общий объект состояния, который запущенные потоки могут изменять и который можно произвольно читать? В примере что-то вроде глобального счетчика, так?

Comment: В примере написано "Ссылки будут использоваться в потоках которые будет создавать эта структура."  Структура одна, потоков использующие ее много, цель была используя структуру и потоки внутри ее и self функцию получить ее Arc self и раздать потокам.  (fn(Arc<self>))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это потому, что self лежит внутри Arc, и там где у вас self - там на самом деле вы хотите Arc. В плюсах для такого есть `shared_from_this()`, раст считает, что вам это ненадо.

Мы когда-то "упражнялись" - и родили почти рабочий код, содержащий уйму подводных камней. Через unsafe и арифметику на указателях, с учетом алигнментов, технически-возможно извратиться - и получить Rc или Arc из &self. Но - только для структур. С трейтами там все сложней, так как для алингнмента нужен vtable, а его нет. Но даже для структур, там все держится на довольно зыбких предположениях. Только для удовлетворения академического интереса: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f095b498ad8994cf6950740f0228bef0&version=nightly

Думаю, что про shared_from_this в раст нужно просто забыть. Его нет и его не будет.

Так что, предлагаю вместо &self передавать в функции Arc, и там его разименовывать, а от поля внутри структуры отказаться совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка внутри структуры на часть ее содержимого имеет сомнительную пользу. Можно предложить использовать `Arc<RwLock<_>>` над всей структурой в явном виде. Значения этого типа достаточно удобно клонировать и брать RAII доступ к их содержимому благодаря неявному `Deref` и автоматической реализации `Clone`.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::thread;

/// Мой Nanite содержит только счетчик
pub struct Nanite {
    count: u64,
}

impl Nanite {
    // Метод new(), по конвенции, конструирует значение типа Self,
    // поэтому выбрал более затейливое имя
    pub fn new_shared() -> Arc<RwLock<Nanite>> {
        Arc::new(RwLock::new(Nanite { count: 0 }))
    }

    pub fn increment(&mut self) {
        self.count += 1000;
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> u64 { self.count }
}

// Вынес из Nanite: потоки, предполагаю, делают что-то еще и увеличивают
// счетчик, поэтому к внутренностям Nanite не имеют отношения.
fn start(nan: &Arc<RwLock<Nanite>>) -> Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> {
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..5 {
        let nan = nan.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut nan_access = nan.write().unwrap();
                nan_access.increment();
            });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    handles
}

fn main() {
    let nan = Nanite::new_shared();
    let handles = start(&nan);
    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(2_000));
    println!("Count: {}", nan.read().unwrap().value());
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Больше информации на тему есть во [втором издании Книги](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-03-shared-state.html).

Comment: Дополнительный совет: `Mutex` на практике гораздо быстрее, чем `RwLock`, если одновременных читателей ожидается немного. Вдобавок, содержимое `RwLock` обязано удовлетворять `Sync + Send`, а для содержимого `Mutex` достаточно `Send`.